# Unable to authenticate against Core Service LDAP

Tags: core-service, dxa, web8.5, ldap

Got a really strange issue that I can not seem to resolve.  We have a fresh Web 8.5 installation that is HTTPS and LDAP enabled using the setup scripts, but Core service when trying to install DXA 1.6 is constantly failing with a Message Security verification failed error according to Svc trace logs.

> Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "An unsecured or incorrectly secured
>   fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."
>   At C:\Users\mherbert\Downloads\SDL.DXA.NET.1.6\cms\cms-import.ps1:132 char:22
>   + $coreServiceClient = Get-CoreServiceClient "Service"
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CoreServiceClient], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MessageSecurityException,Get-CoreServiceClient

This was configured using the SetupLDAP and SetupHTTPS scripts so unsure what else could be missing or incorrect.  Web 8.5 itself has a Self signed certificate on the server, and a load balancer with a different certifcate that passes all traffic back to the server over HTTPS.

Further to that, I do see the below errors in event viewer as well

> Invalid user name or password. Please verify your user name or password. The user name was username.
>
> Component: LdapAuthenticationHttpModule
>
> Errorcode: 6
>
> User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>      at Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.AuthenticateUser(String userName, String password)
>      at Tridion.Security.Web.LdapAuthenticationHttpModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Which parameters are you providing to the cms-import.ps1 script? You should specify `-cmsAuth Basic` and provide username & password.

Comment: -cmsAuth -cmsUsername and -cmsUserPassword was specified.  Have reinstalled Web 8 now not using HTTPS and worked around it by setting up SSO and AD using the same Directory service name as the domain itself.  Although there are still some issues with Core service but will look in to that further, managed to work around the immediate issue with a vanilla install of Web 8 with no SSO integration initially.  Odd that LDAP and SSO used to work on T2013 but not on Web 8 though.

Answer (score 1):

Basing my answer on your comment:

> -cmsAuth -cmsUsername and -cmsUserPassword was specified. Have reinstalled Web 8 now not using HTTPS and worked around it by setting up SSO and AD using the same Directory service name as the domain itself. Although there are still some issues with Core service but will look in to that further, managed to work around the immediate issue with a vanilla install of Web 8 with no SSO integration initially. Odd that LDAP and SSO used to work on T2013 but not on Web 8 though.

In general when trying to setup DXA on a Web 8 machine which is not correctly installed/configured will always result in errors, as the DXA installation scripts are using the SDL Web APIs (and if they don;t work, it will fail somewhere).

Furthermore, assuming that something which worked before on your 2013 setup is now not working because you couldn't get it to work, is a bit of an overstatement. Whether there is an issue with Web 8 or not in relation to LDAP and SSO I simply don't know, and from the information given by you I don't think anybody can conclude that. Those type of conclusions I would like to be made by Customer Support, with the added benefot that it then is registered as an issue and will be adressed in a next release.